# I want to do an Excel indirect lookup to another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where cells have a drop down that refers to a list via an indirect formula.

The dropdown cell is meant to be a count value of an instrument
e.g.

```
Item
Apples
Bananas
Eggs
```

---

The Count utility is another list with the item in 1 column, a minimum number in the second column, the maximum number in the third column and a counter from 1-10 in the fourth.

The dropdown looks up the item and picks its max and min number and creates a dynamic list of numbers from 1-10 using the counter list.

This is the formula that I have to do this.

```
=INDIRECT("$Z$"&$X2+1&":$Z$"&$Y2+1)
```

The Z is the counter list from 1-10
The X is the minimum number
The Y is the maximum number

What I am trying to do is have this list moved to another worksheet, but all my attempts have failed.

I have tried varying combinations of the following

`=INDIRECT("'" $Instruments$"'!" & "$Z$"&$X2+1&":$Z$"&$Y2+1)` but excel does not like the forumla.

I know I am using the wrong syntax, but I can't figure out where I am incorrect.

Comment: assuming that, in Sheet1, `A2=INDIRECT("$Z$"&$X2+1&":$Z$"&$Y2+1)`, in your cell of sheet2, use fomula `= Indirect("Sheet1!A2")`

Comment: I tried what you recommended, but it did not work.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work either    =INDIRECT("Instruments!$E$"&$C2+1&":Instruments!$E$"&$D2+1)

Comment: see below reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, worksheet quote is  Sheet1!A1:A3 (e.g.)
by indirect, it is `=indirect（"Sheet1!A1:A3")`
In your code, e.g. the correct format should be:`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$Z$1:$Z$3")`

So you must tell indirect that the cell `X2` and `Y2` is belong to `Sheet1`.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$Z$" & Sheet1!$X2+1 & ":$Z$"&Sheet1!$Y2+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
=INDIRECT("Instruments!$Z$"&$X2+1&":$Z$"&$Y2+1)
```

I would also consider using `R1C1` notation. It removes the confusing `$` and allows you to do computations on the column as well as the row (if need be).

```
=INDIRECT("Instruments!R"&RC24+1&"C26:R"&RC25+1&"C26",FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I tried both options but they both say the Named Range cannot be found.

Comment: @AndrewH - I assumed from your question that you defined the `Instruments` as a named range.

Comment: @AndrewH - Are you saying that you just have a sheet called `Instruments`?

Comment: I may have not expressed myself well. I have 2 sheets. A tracker sheet and an instrument sheet and i wanted to reference the instrument sheet from the tracker sheet.

Comment: Thanks again, but it still does not filter the information